# autocomplete with MySQLi and php(via Autocomplete UI)

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, autocomplete

I am trying to make an autocomplete php interacts with database, but find more than 10 online resource, cannot make it work with my database.
Here is the index.php code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            //autocomplete
            $("#model").autocomplete({
                source: "search.php",
                minLength: 1
            });                

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='' method='post'>
<p><label>Model:</label><input type='text' id="model" name='model' class='model'/></p>
```

```
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the search.php:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '123456');
define('DB_NAME', 'inventory');

if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $return_arr = array();

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    $stmt =  $conn->stmt_init();
    $term = '%'.$_GET['term'].'%';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name from items WHERE name like ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $term);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($models);
    while( $row = $models){
        $return_arr[] =  $row['name'];
    }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
}  
?>
```

And some tutorial use fetch_array() that is not working on my script why? It only work with regular loop such as while loop to store array from database and then use foreach to echo every rows. I am using `$mysqli->fetch_array()`.
Which part is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

Replace the "bind_result" line with this (just for convenience):

```
$stmt->bind_result($name);
```

Then replace your while loop with this:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $return_arr[] = $name;
}
```

And it should work.

Basically for each column in your query you add a variable in the bind_result statement and use those when iterating over the results;

Answer (score -1):

use below codes and go through the url@,
http://www.codexworld.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/

```
//get matched data from skills table
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE skill LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY skill ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['skill'];
}

//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
```